# iOS: Where and how I can get the cities list (not preloaded in local DB)?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, geocoding

I am writting the code for iOS in Swift. And I cannot set up with any idea how to getcities list for searching throught it.
I don't want to create any preloaded local DB. Is there way to get this list from iOS or I should use some third party API? Could you help me, please. Thanks!

Comment: By Googling you'll see that you have to use an external API found on internet and parse results from it. Like for example : http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/

Answer (score 0):

In case you decide to use the Google API:

```
    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=\(searchString)&sensor=true&types=(cities)&key=\(GOOGLE_API_KEY)"
    let url:NSURL! = NSURL(string: urlString)

    if url != nil {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var err:NSError?
        var citySearchResults = [String]()

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response:NSURLResponse!, data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:&err) as? NSDictionary {
                    self.citySearchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    for prediction in json["predictions"] as! Array<NSDictionary> {
                        if let addressComponents:Array<String>! = (prediction["description"] as! NSString).componentsSeparatedByString(",") as? Array<String> {
                            if addressComponents!.count > 2 {
                                citySearchResults.append("\(addressComponents![0]),\(addressComponents![1])")
                            } else {
                                citySearchResults.append(prediction["description"] as! String)
                            }
                        } else {
                            citySearchResults.append(prediction["description"] as! String)
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```